# How to open file in C, what is different between (argv[1], "r") and ("file name", "r")

Tags: c

How to open file by (argv[1], "r")?
My lab3.txt file is in same directory folder.

I can open file by

```
FILE *f = fopen("lab3.txt", "r");
```

but why I cannot open file by

```
FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
char buf[512];

FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error!\n");

}


fread(buf, 512, 1, f);

printf("buf: %s\n", buf);

if (chkserial(buf) == 0)
    fullversion();
else
    trialversion();

return 0;
```

}

Comment: How are you running your program?

Comment: Your code is correct, you're probably doing something else wrong. You need to specify the exact file name. Is the file called `lab3` or `lab3.txt`? You also don't specify which operating system you use and how you execute the program. What does "same folder" mean? The folder of the executable program? That's not necessarily the working directory in which relative path names are looked up.

Comment: please `printf ("%s", argv[1])` to know which string value is inject to the fopen function.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the argument count your process that's running the program executable holds, and then make sure you are also calling it with the right amount of cli arguments.

Cli arguments are laid out as follows

```
<program> <foo.txt> <doo.txt> ...

argv[0]    argv[1]   argv[2]  ... argv[n]
```

Therefore, you want to call your executable like this

```
your_exec_name lab3.txt
```

You may also want to add a check to make sure the program is run with at least one argument to prevent a segfault or passing in `NULL` to `fopen`

```
if(argc < 2) { /*Handling goes here*/ exit(1);}
```

Comment: I think that about covers it.

Comment: Thank u, it works, I only have one txt file, so I need to call ./exec_name lab3.txt